# Prestart and pretest script in angular seed project

Tags: angularjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start, angular-seed

I am using [angular seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/tree/master) as a skeleton for my angularjs app. The `package.json` contains two scripts-

1. `prestart` and
2. `pretest`

Both run `npm install` when I run the server with the `npm start` command.

I don't want to install packages whenever I start the server. However, if I want to update my dependencies, then I can use `update-deps`.

Are these scripts mandatory to use, or we can omit them? Will they have any consequences if I remove them? If yes, then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running `npm install` manually and nothing is removing/modifying `node_modules` or `package*.json` in the lifecycle, then those `pretest` and `prestart` scripts (that do `npm install` and nothing else) can be omitted.

If you are 100% sure that you do not want or need lifecycle scripts like `prestart`/`poststart` and `pretest`/`posttest` but don't want to modify the `package.json` for any reason, you can use `--ignore-scripts`:

```
npm --ignore-scripts test
```

It seems that those lifecycle scripts are there just as a convenience for those who run `npm start` or `npm test` without running `npm install` first. They can be safely removed.